# Wrong screen resolution sometimes after sleep, with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, display

After my Lenovo T480s connected to a Benq 4k display wakes from sleep, my resolution goes to 1080p, unplugging and plugging the display back in resets it to 4k. (This doesn't always happen, but I find usually it does when the laptop automatically sleeps)

I checked out `xrandr` after waking and this is the output: (I removed the integrated display options because they don't change)

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 708mm x 399mm
   1920x1080     60.00*   60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00    50.00  
   720x480       60.00    60.00    59.94    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

After unplugging and plugging back in, these two lines are prepended to the list:

```
   3840x2160     60.00*+  30.00  
   2560x1440     59.95
```

System specs:

- **Model**: Lenovo T480s 20L7
- **OS**: Ubuntu 18.10
- **Desktop**: GNOME 3.30.1
- **CPU**: i7 8550U
- **GPU**: UHD 620 iGPU
- **Display**: Benq BL3201PH (3840x2160@60Hz)
- **Display cable**: Choetech USB-C to DisplayPort

Comment: _jjmirks_, would you please click on [edit] and advise if your Lenovo T480S is a 20L5, 20L6, 20L7, or 20L8? Also, please advise the model number of the Benq display, for there are many different 4k displays on their web pages. Lastly, which release number of Ubuntu is in use, and which desktop did you choose? All of these may be vital in providing a solution, and by clicking [edit] and refining your original question with these useful facts, everyone will see the update.